# Is the [meta] tag a synonym of [meta-tags]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

[meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta)'s excerpt states:

> Meta elements are the HTML or XHTML element used to provide structured metadata about a Web page.

[meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags)'s:

> Meta tags are HTML elements used to provide structured metadata about a Web page placed in the head section of a document.

Those seem to be the same thing to me.

Could a mod merge them?

Comment: Don't you try to confuse us here ;-) ...

Comment: But confusing you is so much fun!

Comment: The answer seems to be yes. Just don't confuse it with the meta-tag [meta-tag:meta].

Comment: @Deduplicator I think you mean the meta meta-tag? ;)

Comment: On main site, yes... but here on Meta, [meta-tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) is different from [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta) tag.

Comment: @Scimonster Ever read Douglas Hofstadter's _"Gödel, Escher, Bach"_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I started it, never finished. But yeah, meta-meta-meta-meta...

Comment: @Scimonster If you've read to the end, you should have noticed _Gödel_ was the guy who fixed it. Though Schrödingers thought experiments gave us a hard reality shock ;-P ... (and a lot of stinky dead cats, because everyone forgot just to feed them)

Comment: @Scimonster Though I'm impressed you came over that book at all. For me it was ages ago (not that young you are now, but I think I was 21 or 22). Heads up! Read it to the end, read that book several times (as I did), enjoy Escher and Bach!

Comment: maybe renaming 'em al' to [html-meta-tag] instead... *head hurts*